# Alfresco-Retrieve Cancelled Workflows

Tags: alfresco, activiti

Using Alfresco & Share (currently testing on version 5.2). Using the standard Workflow "My Task" interface to create and (in this case) cancel workflows.

The details of user cancelled workflows are required, any history or contents will be useful (if they still exist) after cancellation by the user.

Whether or not this is available through the existing UI or some repository side code is fine. Just some direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Stephen

Answer (score 1):

In the side panel you can see

[image: side panel]

Click on completed and you can see the workflow list, click on any workflow it will give you history.

[image: alfresco-admin console]

Comment: Thanks deshi, I've just tried this on a fresh install of 5.2 and it does not seem to show cancelled workflows. Start a workflow, go to 'Workflows I've Started' and select one then 'Cancel Workflow' at the bottom. Seems to completely vanish from existence in my experience (logical outcome actually). Unless there's a setting somewhere to enable this?

Comment: Could you please check Alfresco Administration Console (admin only), by login to /alfresco, there you can pass "show definitions"  command, then some detail should be there about deleted workflow also, there you can get workflow id.